# Grep, How to pattern match a multiple bracketed strings on one line

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, grep

I have some data which includes a bunch of bracketed codes, sometimes multiple on one line.

```
Lorem ipsum  (ABC123) dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit (BCD234)
sed do  (345CDE) eiusmod tempor (8675309) incididunt
```

All my attempts to pull out the bracketed strings (`grep -P -i -o "(?<=\().*(?=\))"` and `grep -E -i -o "\(CAS.*\)"`) have resulted in an output like:

```
ABC123
BCD234
345CDE) eiudmod tempor (8675309
```

whereas what I need is :

```
ABC123
BCD234
345CDE
8675309
```

How should I go about this?  I'm using GNU grep.

I bonus would not be broken by unmatched brackets and pull out `ABC123`  from `ut labore (et dolore (ABC123) magna aliqua` but that's not too important.

Comment: Just use lazy matching: `"(?<=\().*?(?=\))"`

Comment: `grep -oP '\(\K[^()]+(?=\))' file` would work for the bonus case as well..

Comment: if you add `ut labore (et dolore (ABC123) magna aliqua` as part of sample input, I think this question would not be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '\(\K.*?(?=\))' inputfile
```

> ABC123
>   
> BCD234
>   
> 345CDE
>   
> 8675309