# Java Regex how to get all the matching occurences of a pattern

Tags: java, regex

Here is the string

```
abcd&fq=-(( +ExpirationDate:[* TO *]  -ExpirationDate:[2016-12-13T08:00:00Z TO *]))&fq=-SupplierId:\"systemid:1000008557\"&fq=-Id:\"systemid:1000009073\"&rows=20&arches.preview=false&sort=score desc,DefaultRelevance desc&bmf=50&wt=text";
```

Would like to get the below as the output

```
fq=-(( +ExpirationDate:[* TO *]  -ExpirationDate:[2016-12-13T08:00:00Z TO *]))

fq=-Id:\"systemid:1000008557\"&fq=-Id:\"systemid:1000009073\"
```

Tried as below

```
String regex = "fq=.*&";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
matcher = p.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

But got output as

```
fq=-SupplierId:\"systemid:1000008557\"&fq=-Id:\"systemid:1000009073\"&rows=20&arches.preview=false&sort=score desc,DefaultRelevance desc&bmf=50&
```

Comment: That's because `*` is greedy. Change to `fq=([^&]+)`

Comment: @MarounMaroun why not put that as an answer?

Comment: @Baby Found a duplicate, prefer to close.

Comment: Or [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)