# Regex find a string with hypones in it

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find email within text that is being followed by a key word 'domain'
`preg_match_all("/domain.+\b([a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,3})/im", $input_lines, $output_array);`

my input data is

```
here is some text
capture this domain hi-there-welcome.co
and this domain should be captured yes90well.com
but not this link nolink.com
but not this line of no domain on it
```

I should be able to capture `hi-there-welcome.com` and `yes90well.com`

Comment: Your strings have no `@`. Give them `@`s or remove it from the regex.

Comment: How about https://regex101.com/r/2fI0yE/3?

Comment: Another case of a greedy/lazy quantifiers: use `"/domain.+?\b([a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,3})/i"`. See [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop).

Comment: @chris85 Please post your solution as an answer so that Kal can mark this question as resolved.

Comment: @mickmackusa Wiktor's comment is better. The `.` just needs to be non-greedy.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please post your solution as an answer so that Kal can mark this question as resolved.