# jquery regex to get string between two brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to get every string between `[ch] and [/ch]`

```
var test = "[ch]Bm[/ch] Time flies by when[ch]A[/ch] the night is young[ch]C[/ch]"
var testRE = test.match("\[ch\](.*)\[/ch\]"); alert(testRE[1]);
```

But, the result I get is:

```
h]Bm[/ch] Time flies by when[ch]A[/ch] the night is young[ch]C[/c
```

How to store every string inside an array?
My desired result is become

```
chords = ["Bm","A","C"]
```

Comment: i'm sorry, why you downvote my question? @wiktor-stribiżew I have search for similar question and didn't found any. When i see this question, it seems different from my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop

Comment: There are too many identical questions. Posting and answering this  one is not necessary, it has been answered many times. 2 more links added. + 677 and 25 upvotes for the same answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current pattern is a minor but tricky one:

```
\[ch\](.*)\[/ch\]
```

The `.*` quantity will consume as much as possible between `[ch]` and `[/ch]`.  This means that you will always just get one match here:

```
Time flies by when[ch]A[/ch] the night is young
```

To get each matching pair, make the dot lazy, i.e. use `(.*?)`.  Consider this code:

```js
var test = "[ch]Bm[/ch] Time flies by when[ch]A[/ch] the night is young[ch]C[/ch]"
var regex = /\[ch\](.*?)\[\/ch\]/g
var matches = [];
var match = regex.exec(test);
while (match != null) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(test);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex `/\[ch\](.*?)\[\/ch\]/g`

```js
var test = "[ch]Bm[/ch] Time flies by when[ch]A[/ch] the night is young[ch]C[/ch]"
var regex = /\[ch\](.*?)\[\/ch\]/g;
var testRE = [];
var match;
while (match = regex.exec(test)) {
    testRE.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(testRE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `split` and `filter`

```
test.split(/\[ch\]|\[\/ch\]/).filter( (s,i ) => i % 2 == 1 )
```

**Demo**

```js
var test = "[ch]Bm[/ch] Time flies by when[ch]A[/ch] the night is young[ch]C[/ch]"
var output = test.split(/\[ch\]|\[\/ch\]/).filter((s, i) => i % 2 == 1);

console.log(output);
```

**Explanation**

- `Split` by either `[ch]` or `[/ch]`
- `filter`-in **even indices**.