# How can I get several matches using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I am trying to get all the matches with a string starting with `[&` and ends with `]` (for example `[&Prueba]`).

So far I have this expression `\[&.*]`
The problem is that if I have two or more matches, it considered them as one, I mean for example

```
dsdd [&xD]s wpxxxxx.php [&dsdd]
```

The regular expression throws one match, this: `[&xD]s wpxxxxx.php [&dsdd]` and I want to get two results: `[&xD]` and `[&dsdd]`

How can I get that? I have tried several things and I'm still not getting it.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Try `\[&[^\]]*]` or `\[&.*?]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
\[&[^\]]+\]
```

Here is an example in python:

```
import re

data = "dsdd [&xD]s wpxxxxx.php [&dsdd]"
results = re.findall("\[&[^\]]+\]", data)
print (results)

['[&xD]', '[&dsdd]']
```

The key part is the negative character class surround by the square brackets (with the first one having an ampersand).  That matches [ , all non ] and finally ]

This is a good site to play around with stuff like this:  https://regex101.com/