# Google Sheets Regexextract

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formulas

If i have a string like `abc_xyz`, i can use `=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "(.*)_")` to extract `abc` from it. But if i have a string like `abc_xyz_qwe`, the function will return `abc_xyz`.

So can you help me figure out how to get the formula to return only `abc` if there are multiple values separated by underscores in the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)

Comment: Or `([^_]+)` to get non-underscores

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Regex, so how do i use that? I understand the ^ symbolizes the start of the string but im not sure what the rest is doing

Comment: @Abhay The suggestion is for you to use `(.*?)_` instead of just `(.*)_`.  Using the former tells the regex engine to stop at the _first_ underscore, which is the behavior you want.

Comment: When you don't know what a pattern is doing, you can plug it into an analyzer like on regex101

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaced `=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "(.*)_")` with `=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "([^_]+)")` and it started picking the part of the string before the first underscore.

Credit to: @CertainPerformance for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
=left(B2,find("_",B2)-1)
```