# pick out the characters up to a certain character in a string

Tags: regex

This is my data

> ABCD01MAH_processor_B_stats_qwer_20181105T105946Z.csv ABCD01MAH_processor_B_stats_qwer_20181106T105945Z.csv   EFGHIJ01MAH_processor_A_stats_qwer_20181105T105945Z.csv EFGHIJ01MAH_processor_A_stats_qwer_20181106T105945Z.csv

and i want to pick out every thing up to the first `underscore`

How do I do this?

This is my attempt, using lookahead conditional `(?(?=...)yes|no)`, but it does it up to the last `underscore` 
e.g. `(?<name1>\w+(?=_))` 
https://regex101.com/r/qJ2fL6/1 
To get it to pick everything up to the first `underscore`
I have to do the following. 
`(?<name1>\w+(?=_p))`
which works for what I want, in that i get the following:

> ABCD01MAH
>   ABCD01MAH
>   EFGHIJ01MAH
>   EFGHIJ01MAH
>   But am I using it right?

How do I get pick up the character, more generally, up to the 1st undrscore? 
How do I get pick up the character, more generally, up to the 2nd undrscore? 
How do I get pick up the character, more generally, up to the 3rd undrscore?

example of what I would like:

 1st

> ABCD01MAH

2nd

> ABCD01MAH_processor

3rd

> EFGHIJ01MAH_processor_A

Comment: What programming language/regex tool are you using?  The exact answer you need really depends on this.

Comment: Have you tried `^(((\w+?)_\w+?)_\w+?)_`? Three Capturing groups will pull up to 1st, 2nd, and 3rd. [See it here](https://regex101.com/r/qJ2fL6/4)

Answer (score 1):

For the first portion we can try using:

```
^(.*?)(?=_|$).*$
```

The first capture group would contain the first path.  For up to an including the second path, we can use:

```
^(.*?_.*?)(?=_|$).*$
```

More generally, for up to and including the Nth term:

```
^(.*?(?:_.*?){N-1})(?=_|$).*$
```

So, for 4 terms, `N-1 = 3`, and we can use:

```
^(.*?(?:_.*?){3})(?=_|$).*$
```

### Demo

Comment: Doesn't matter much, when possible, but negative character sets are [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop#comment93020571_22457) than lazy repitition, see https://regex101.com/r/KYn8Sq/2