# Regex how to ignore multiple ( )?

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex string:

```
/rfi .*?(.*) .*?\((.*)\)/i
```

Group 1 finds the rfi number & group 2 returns the contents inside the ( ).
With test string: "*New RFI 087 (Concrete Beam at Planter)*" everything works fine,
but with test string "*New RFI 087 (Concrete (Beam) at Planter)*" it crashes.

Is there anyway to search inside the ( ) but ignore multiple ( ) inside of it ?

Comment: Use `/rfi (.*?) .*?\((.*)\)/i` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/JO29mM/1)), make your Group 1 pattern lazy. Also, the first `.*?` is redundant, remove it.

Comment: This requires a recursive regex, which engine ?

Comment: @sln, reclose as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop, the only thing OP needs is lazy quantifier with Group 1. No recursion required. No need to reopen evident duplicates.

Comment: if you have access to a PCRE or Perl style engine, use this  [(\(((?:\[^()\]++|(?1))*)\))](https://regex101.com/r/ST1mfv/1). if a Java style engine, use this [(?=\()(?:(?=.*?\((?!.*?\1)(.*\)(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\)(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)\[^(\]*(?=\2$)](https://regex101.com/r/fyVory/1)

Comment: `search inside the ( ) but ignore multiple ( ) inside of it` is a _RECURSION_ question _NOT_ a quantifier question. This is about _balanced text_ !!

Comment: Ok, posted a wiki answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match your strings by making your Group 1 pattern lazy. Also, the first `.*?` is redundant, remove it.

Use

```
/rfi (.*?) .*?\((.*)\)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JO29mM/1)

@sln suggests using a regex with a subroutine, but these features are not quite popular with regex engines, Ruby Onigmo or PCRE support them, for example.

```
/rfi (.*?) .*?(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))/i
```

Or a bit more "cross library" (since Onigmo supports `\g<X>` recursive construct, same as PCRE)

```
/rfi (.*?) .*?(\((?:[^()]++|\g<2>)*\))/i
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/JO29mM/2).

Comment: `but these features are not quite popular with regex engines` What does this mean ?