# Regex for strings containing substring that contains substring

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have this string:

```
[section][module_text id="123"]text[/module][module_number id=""]000[/module][/section]
```

I can find each entire `[module...[/module...]` substring with

```
(\[module)(.*?)(\[\/module.*?\])
```

But I would like to only match the `[module]` string that has a digit in the `id=""` parameter. In this case the first `[module]`.

I've been trying a bunch of stuff but i cant seem to get any closer.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want tu use XML with an XML parser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After matching `module`, you can match non-`]` characters until you get to the `id` part, and after the `id`'s `"`, you can match `[^"]*\d` to ensure that the `id` has a digit in it:

```
(\[module[^]]*id="[^"]*\d)(.*?)(\[\/module[^]]*\])
```

https://regex101.com/r/25JcEP/1

If the `module`s you want to match have `id`s which always *start with* digits, then you can simplify it a bit to

```
(\[module[^]]*id="\d)(.*?)(\[\/module[^]]*\])
```

Note the use of a negative character class rather than `.*?` for the final `(\[\/module[^]]*\])` - negative character classes are [a bit more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop#comment93020571_22457) than lazy repetition when possible.