# Replace [h:12[x] with <span class="h">x</span>

Tags: javascript, regex

I have String structure like:

```
let originalString = "I am a [h:12[x] with [l:3[y] and also with [m[z] which i want to replace."
```

I want to replace the sequence [h:12[x] with `<span class="h">x</span>` and [m[z] to `<span class="m">z</span>`.

The resultant string should look like.

```
I am a <span class="h">x</span> with <span class="l">y</span> and also with <span class="m">z</span>  which i want to replace.
```

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: `.replace('[h:12[x]', '<span class="h">x</span>')`...?

Comment: @Justinas and what if `x` is something else?

Comment: @Oram OP does not asks anything else, just this string to be replaced with other string

Comment: @Justinas `I want to replace the sequence [h:12[x] with x and [m[z] to z.` he clearly does ask for something else.

Comment: Why downvoting the question?

Comment: You should try solving your problem before asking others to do it for you.
People expect you to share what you tried when asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use a regular expression to match `[h:12[x]`-like substrings, extract the word characters following the first and second `[`, then replace with `span` HTML text, with those groups inserted at the appropriate point:

```js
const originalString = "I am a [h:12[x] with [l:3[y] and also with [m[z] which i want to replace.";
const output = originalString.replace(
  /\[(\w+)[^\[]*\[(\w+)\]/g,
  (_, g1, g2) => `<span class="${g1}">${g2}</span>`
);
console.log(output);
```

The pattern `/\[(\w+)[^\[]*\[(\w+)\]/` means:

`\[` - match a literal `[`

`(\w+)` - *capture* one or more word characters in a group

`[^\[]*` - match zero or more non-`[` characters

`\[` - match a literal `[` again

`(\w+)` - *capture* one or more word characters in a group again

`\]` - match a literal `]`

Comment: does not work properly if x,y,z is replaced with any utf8 character.
\[(\w+)\] needs to be replaced with \[(.*?)\]

Comment: Your question does not specify what could exist at that place in the string. Note that [negative character classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop#comment93020571_22457) are more efficient than lazy repetition - eg `[^\[]*`