# Splitting a string by space, ignoring spaces in nested strings

Tags: javascript

Currently, I can split a string like this:

```
"1 2 3".split(' ') // [ "1", "2", "3" ]
"1 2 3 'word'".split(' ') // [ "1", "2", "3", "'word'" ]
```

Is there a way to avoid splitting on a space within a nested string?

For example:

```
"1 2 3 'word one'".split(' ') // want output of [ "1", "2", "3", "'word one'" ]
"1 2 3 \"word one\"".split(' ') // want output of [ "1", "2", "3", "\"word one\"" ]
```

I want output of `[ "1", "2", "3", "'word one'" ]` instead of `[ "1", "2", "3", "'word", "one'" ]` (i.e. I want to ignore spaces if they are in strings).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To correctly match strings containing additional quote characters, when matching substrings in quotes, lazy-repeat the `.` with `.+?`, otherwise strings such as

```
1 "2" "3"
```

won't match properly. Also, unless you can count on all matches containing just word characters, probably better to use `\S` (which will match anything but whitespace characters):

```js
var s = `1 "2" "3" foo'bar`
console.log(s.match(/'.+?'|".+?"|\S+/g));
```

Or, to be [slightly more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop#comment93020571_22457), rather than lazy repetition, use negative character classes instead:

```js
var s = `1 "2" "3" foo'bar`
console.log(s.match(/'[^']+'|"[^"]+"|\S+/g));
```

Answer (score 6):

One approach can be to use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex that accounts for the spaces inside quotes:

```js
var s = "1 2 3 \"word one\" one \"two\" 'hello world'";

console.log(s.match(/'[^']+'|"[^"]+"|\w+/g));
```

**Edit**: See [Certain Performance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530341/1822698) for a better regex.

Comment: This will match too much if the string contains more quote characters later, eg `1 "2" "3"`. `\w` also assumes word characters, which may well not be the case.

Answer (score -1):

Walk through the string and keep a Boolean flag for if you're within quotes.

```
if(string[i] == ' ' && !insideQuotes) //split
```