# How replace JUST domain wildcard and not whole line?

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I am trying to replace long URLs with a new domain that just go to the root, but when I use the wildcard, it is replacing more than just the URL but code that is written after it

I tried adding what to search for after the wildcard, which would be a quote `"` but it doesnt seem to stop at the FIRST quote.

for example I was using

`find: site1.com/.*"
replace:site2.com/shop`

but it is giving me

`site1.com/2018/02/08/best-cannabis-strains-relieve-stress/" rel="canonical" /><meta property="og:locale"`

and keeps going.
How do I make the wildcard string stop at the FIRST `"` and not keep going

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem: `site1\.com\/[^"]*`

`[^"]` means: anything but a quote.

If you want to learn more, you should look up regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Can you explain this for a noob like me and maybe future finders? why do you put the .com in \ \ ? Also I want the search to stop at the first quote, because that is when the domain code ends, so I guess that means it will look UP TO that point then stop if I am understanding correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It does not stop at first quote because `*` is a *greedy* quantifier. It means it will find as much as it is able to.

In order to make it *lazy* (that is, stop as soon as possible) you may add `?` to the quantifier. That is: `*?`

So, given this string `aaabaaab`

This regexes will match:

`^.*b` ➡ `aaabaaab`

`^.*?b` ➡ `aaab`

**NOTE**:

The lazy modifier also works for other quantifiers like `?`, `+` and `{}`

As commented on the other answer, another way to stop at the first quote with a greedy quantifier is not using `.`, but `anything but quote character`: `[^"]*"`

Comment: Thank you for dumbing it down for me this helped! It is interesting that there are multiple ways to accomplish the same thing, especially for something as small as a search and replace feature!