# Why does this regex fail to find matching pattern in string?

Tags: regex, vba

I have a file which will contain contents similar to the following example:

```
?[A7]DA<DA-SG
'[G7]G%SD\$DF
#[27]F:./4FFF
?[P9]W3_2SS_F
'[90]GA\\WTER
```

Each line ends in `\r\n`.

From this particular file, I need to replace the `F:./4FFF` part of the line `#[27]F:./4FFF`.

So far to start, I have this pattern in order to try and capture the part I need to replace:

```regex
\#\[27\]([\w\W]*)\r\n
```

The problem is that between the closing `]` and the `\r\n`, could be any alphanumeric character or symbol.

I think the problem lies in the capturing group???  What is the correct pattern for this; I will be doing this in VBA.

Comment: Try `\#\[27\]([\w\W]*?)\r\n`. You don’t want `[\w\W]` to match the next `\r\n`, so match as few characters as possible.

Comment: Is there any pattern to match `F:./4FFF` or would `^(#\[27\]).*`and replace with group 1 also be ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be trying to design an expression, that would somewhat look like:

```
(?<=^#\[\d{2}\])\S*
```

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/TVzJ40/1/)

Or maybe just:

```
^(#\[\d+\])\S*
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/gfmTOF/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the multiline option with these (regex.MULTILINE or something)

Two ways to do it

`^#\[27\](.*)`

or

`^#\[27\]([^\r\n]*)`

The thing is that `\r\n` is not needed to stop the match on the line.
It goes to the end without matching them.
This is advantageous if the line is the *last one* in the file.