# I am trying to select in my regex only what is between `<` and `-`

Tags: regex

I am trying to select in my regex only what is between `<` and `-`

**Regex**

```
<(.*)-
```

**STRING**

```
<SM1-SRVNET-P:Sys
```

**OUTPUT**

```
SM1-SRVNET
```

**Desired Exit**

```
SM1
```

[REGEX101.COM](https://regex101.com/r/6a14Dm/1)

Comment: Make it non greedy `.*?` or use `<([^-]+)-` Take the value from the first capturing group.

Comment: Comment the answer please, to select it!

Comment: It is a common issue as the `.*` is overmatching it. I am pretty sure there is a dupe somewhere. See this page for an extended explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the "greedy" star operator, so the matching engine keeps matching `.` to the end of the string and eventually backtracks to the second `-`.

You want to have it try to match what follows (here `-`) after *every* match of `.`. You make it do this with the "lazy" star. It's lazy in the sense that it matches shortest string possible.

So try `<(.*?)-`.

Another approach that's actually a bit more efficient is to match all but `-` with the greedy star.  That's `<([^-]*)-`.