# Replace reoccuring substring with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove the table descriptions from the following text so that only the non table text remains.  I have been playing with regex101.com but can't seem to find pattern that actually does this (it always takes the whole section).  What am I missing here?

> TABLE 37-1 Text over multiple lines that describes the table (.pdf)
>
> Non table text.
>
> TABLE 37-2 Text over multiple lines that describes the table (.pdf)

```
import re
text = 'string of text in block quotes above'
processed_text = re.sub(r'(TABLE)(.|\n)*(\(\.pdf\))', r'', text)
print (processed_text)
```

Comment: show the input and what is the expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)

Comment: Make the regex non-greedy by adding `?` after `(.|\n)*` i.e. `(TABLE)(.|\n)*?(\(\.pdf\))`

Comment: @Nick this still removes the entire block of text rather than stopping at the first "(.pdf)"

Comment: @user3495364 https://rextester.com/XQYLA70648

Comment: Can a line in the non-table text start with TABLE or end with (.pdf)?

Comment: @Nick Sorry your version worked. I had initially typed it as (TABLE)(.*|\n)*?(\(\.pdf\)) (with an extra * after the first period) as it was in my initial version.  So I suppose it was grabbing any number of any character once rather than any character once.  Thank you.

Comment: @user3495364 no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than replacing the unwanted text with the empty string, this extracts the wanted text.

```
>>> import re                                                                   
>>>                                                                             
>>> text = '''TABLE 37-1 Text over multiple 
...: lines that describes the table (.pdf) 
...: Non table text line 1. 
...: Non table text line 2. 
...: TABLE 37-2 Text over multiple 
...: lines that describes the table (.pdf)'''                                   
>>>                                                                             
>>> re.match(r'TABLE.*?\(\.pdf\)\n(.*)TABLE.*?\(\.pdf\)$', text, re.DOTALL).group(1)          
'Non table text line 1.\nNon table text line 2.\n'
```

Should also work if there are `"TABLE ... (.pdf)"` strings in the non-table text.

```
>>> text = '''TABLE 37-1 Text over multiple 
...: lines that describes the table (.pdf) 
...: Non table text line 1. 
...: Non table text line 2. 
...: TABLE 37-2 non table text that 
...: starts with TABLE and ends with (.pdf)(.pdf) 
...: TABLE 37-2 Text over multiple 
...: lines that describes the table (.pdf)'''                                                 
>>>                                                                                           
>>> re.match(r'TABLE.*?\(\.pdf\)\n(.*)TABLE.*?\(\.pdf\)$', text, re.DOTALL).group(1)          
'Non table text line 1.\nNon table text line 2.\nTABLE 37-2 non table text that\nstarts with TABLE and ends with (.pdf)(.pdf)\n'
```