# preg match the absolute first and last tags

Tags: php, regex

I have this code:

```
preg_match_all('/<script>(.*)<\/script>/', $matches[0], $page_script);
```

Page html:

```
<script>some_script_data</script>
<script>some_more_script_data</script>
```

What I expected is 2 results like:

```
[
   0 => "<script>some_script_data</script>",
   1 => "<script>some_more_script_data</script>"
]
```

What I get is :

```
[
   0 => "<script>some_script_data</script><script>some_more_script_data</script>"
]
```

So it is taking everything between the very fist `<script>` and the very `</script>`. How can I solve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22449/5527985

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but need to access the result slightly different. Take a look at that:

```
<?php
$markup = <<<HTML
<script>some_script_data</script>
<script>some_more_script_data</script>
HTML;
preg_match_all('/<script>(.*)<\/script>/', $markup, $scripts);
print_r($scripts);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <script>some_script_data</script>
            [1] => <script>some_more_script_data</script>
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => some_script_data
            [1] => some_more_script_data
        )
)
```

Comment: No no, the problem is that even with HTML markup, it still returns the text between the first `script` tag and the last `</script>`. Means the inner script opening and closing tags are not considered as matches.

Comment: it still returns `<script>some_script_data</script>
<script>some_more_script_data</script>` as result :/

Comment: No, it does not. The output I posted is exactly what it outputs if I execute that code.

Comment: And what I posted is not some special "HTML markup". It is a simple string definition called "Heredoc". You can read about it in the documentation. It simply makes code easier to read. But there is no magic in that.