# Regex to match a part of a path in C++

Tags: c++, regex, regexp-replace

I'm having issues trying to come up with a regex in order to match a part of a path and then use the second capture group to extract it

let suppose that we have the following paths:

./var/lib/

var/lib/

./var/lib

from those examples that section of the string that I'm trying to match would be just (var/lib) for all those inputs, so I decided to try using a regex.

This is what I have so far:

`(\.\/)?[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\/]+(\/)?$`

So far it matches all the possible scenarios but it does not match the last capture group.

so for example ./var/lib/test/ is matched correctly, but the las / is not matched by the third capture group but for the second one and I cannot have that.

the correct behavior should be:

| First group | Second Group | Third group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ./ | var/lib/test | / |

Comment: Have you tried experimenting on e.g. [regex101](https://regex101.com)? It can show you lots of information about the regexes to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: XY problem? Did you try **`std::filesystem::path`**? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path it has a variety of convenience functions to get you rid of most of such considerations.

Comment: `(\.\/)?((\/?[A-Za-z0-9]+)+)(\/)?$` It removes duplication of `A-Za-z0-9` but adds an extra group. So, your group 3 becomes group 4.

Comment: I agree with @Red.Wave. It doesn't sound like regex is the right tool - but `std::filesystem::path` most probably is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a lazy quantifier `+?` instead of greedy `+` (also, you missed second group in your original regex):

```
(\.\/)?([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\/]+?)(\/)?$
```

Lazy quantifier matches as little as possible, but since you require the match to include end of string with `$`, it has no choice but to capture everything except possibly last `/`.

[See online on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/344DHF/1)
[See online on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7erdb6EYv)