Why is my regex not matching the longest substring?
I have the following instruction
re.sub(r'\d?(\d\w+|\wb)', 'z', 'ad2aba')

Since it is supposed to replace the expression  d?(\d\w+|\wb)' by z in ad2aba I thought it will give adz since we try to have the longest expression by default
So i thought d? give nothing
d\w+ give 2aba
And so we replace it by z and have adz but I am incorrect and the result is actually adza and not adz. The function takes d?\wb instead d\w+ which gives a longer expression. I do not understand why. Why choosing that option re.sub is supposed to be greedy and search for the longest one?
Is that the ?d that changes that?

See https://regex101.com/r/DgIOeD/1/debugger. The \d? finds 2, then the \d\w+ cannot match, so \wb matches and finishes (as there is no need to backtrack, a valid match was found).

@Wiktor Why did you close this as a duplicate? OP's asking why the regex didn't behave greedily. They're not asking what the individual symbols mean.

Please fix the formatting. d doesn't have a special meaning without the backslash.

See @WiktorStribiżew 's comment above; I'll add that if you replace \d? with its non-greedy version \d?? you'll get what you expected (because now \d\w+ will get its chance).

@Wiktor OK, I think I get it now. I wasn't aware of ??. Still, the linked question is way too broad to be a proper duplicate target for this and it's missing a link for ??. You could write one here and add the link there.

@wjandrea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match , etc. etc. etc.

I think the OP didn't quite get the way the greediness operated. You comment makes it clear.

The title is pretty vague. If I could suggest a better one: "Why is my regex not matching the longest substring?" For tips on writing a good title, see [ask].

The only problem you had with understanding is that \w matches digits, too. Basic issue, explained by many.

Try the regex101 debugger starting at step 11. The \d? finds 2, then the \d\w+ cannot match, so \wb matches and finishes (as there is no need to backtrack, a valid match was found).
If you replaced \d? with \d?? (the non-greedy version), then it would backtrack and match 2aba.
See also

My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?
Regular expression to stop at first match
Reference - What does this regex mean?, which covers greediness under "Quantifiers"


Regexes match the leftmost longest match, not the longest overall possible. Basically, in the absence of non-greedy quantifier qualifiers, if there is any way to match without backtracking, that is preferred over any match where backtracking is required, regardless of the potential matches' respective lengths.

And it is fixed in this case by making the first optional match also lazy with a second ? to be \d??(\d\w+|\wb) Demo
